# Location permission determiner

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to build a permission determiner class, which basically determine the permission.

So far I've done below code, however I keep getting error in the case statements `case LocationUsage.WhenInUse:` and `case .Always:`.

It says that

> enum case is not a member fo type PrivateResoure.LocationUsage?

What am I doing wrong in this small `struct`?

```
public struct PrivateResource {


  public enum LocationUsage {
      case WhenInUse
      case Always
  }
  var usage: LocationUsage?



  public var isNotDeterminedAuthorization: Bool {

      return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined

  }

  public var isAuthorized: Bool {

          switch usage {
          case LocationUsage.WhenInUse:
              return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse
          case .Always:
              return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedAlways
          }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

- `usage` is an Optional, so you have to unwrap it.
- `.AuthorizedWhenInUse` and `.AuthorizedAlways` are not part of the `CLAuthorizationStatus` choices.

The choices are:

> Authorized, Denied, NotDetermined, Restricted

A quick fix:

```
public var isAuthorized: Bool {

    switch usage! {
    case LocationUsage.WhenInUse:
        return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Authorized
    case .Always:
        return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Authorized
    }

}
```

Two notes: it solves the issue but my example solution changes your logic - you may have to adapt. Also, I've force unwrapped the Optional for this example: I'll let you choose the safest way instead that is adapted for your code.